# Getting Docker private registry URL

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have been trying to deploy [to a Kubernetes cluster] a Docker image that is present in my private Docker registry. So, my private registry in Docker looks like this:

```
summer/my-app:version1.1
```

In order to deploy the app to a Kubernetes cluster, I need to specify the image name in `my-app-deployment.yml` file. This image name however requires a complete path to the registry. Unlike from official Docker images which uses the format like this: `registry.hub.docker.com/<user>/<image>`, it did not work in my case and yielded an error `ImagePullBackOff` during deployment.

Is there a different format to this, when deploying from a private Docker registry?

Comment: Is Kubernetes authorized to pull from the registry? The format registry/user/image looks fine. Just use the same as you would do locally when doing  a `docker login` and put the image namespace after the registry.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I seem to have forgotten to log into Docker from my K8s cluster. It works, now.

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you don't specify which registry to query, then it would use docker.io, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/_print/#image-names

You may however configure default registries.
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man5/containers-registries.conf.5.html

Though I'm not sure docker itself takes this under consideration. It really depends on your runtime. While in a Kubernetes cluster context, those configurations are probably managed by something else (Kops, Kubespray, ...).